# Handling response status in React useEffect hook - lifecycle issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch, react-lifecycle

I'm currently rendering some data by fetching from API within the `useEffect` hook.

I have a `searchValue` variable which holds the value the user inputs on the home page search field. This is passed down to this `component`.

I have set `searchValue` in the `useEffect` dependencies so that when it changes it will run the effect again.

When it mounts, it seems to be skipping the `!res.ok` if statement. I have logged the `res.ok` to the console outside of this if statement and with each character inputted into the `searchValue` it always comes back `true`. The response status is always 200 after a character press so it never runs the `!res.ok` if statement block. Something must be wrong with my understanding of the lifecycle or asynchronous calls.

I am getting the error: `countriesData.map is not a function` - so it is trying to render the `map` on invalid data however this should not even return since I have `if (error)` written first within the `Content` function. If this is matched it should return the error message instead, but this is skipped and the `countriesData` is updated with invalid data. My code is below, please help! I feel like I'm missing something simple and misunderstanding some fundamentals of React!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import CountryCard from '../CountryCard'
import { countries } from './CountriesList.module.css'

const CountriesList = ({ searchValue }) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [countriesData, setCountriesData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCountries = async () => {
            let res = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v2/all')
            if (searchValue !== '') {
                res = await fetch(
                    `https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${searchValue}`
                )
            }

            if (!res.ok) {
                console.log(res)
                return setError(true)
            }

            const data = await res.json()
            setCountriesData(data)
            setLoading(false)
        }

        getCountries()

        // return () => setLoading(true)
    }, [searchValue])

    const Content = () => {
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: please check the country you have typed</div>
        }

        if (loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return (
            <section className={`${countries} columns is-multiline`}>
                {countriesData.map((country) => (
                    <CountryCard {...country} key={country.name} />
                ))}
            </section>
        )
    }

    return <Content />
}

export default CountriesList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must be mistaken about the shape of `countriesData`. You initialise it to an empty array, so `.map` will work on that. Then the only place you change it is `setCountriesData(data)` - so this must not be an array.

Comment: Ah yes didn't even think about that cheers. It looks like when an incorrect name is used the API returns a single object whereas when it's valid it returns an array of objects.

Comment: This was the issue. Fixed and solved, didn't even think to check what was being returned from API. rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you are setting array to countriesData, then you can fix by just adding Optional chaining syntax.

replace     `countriesData.map` with

```
countriesData?.map
```

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)